# Check if available values of a list-field is already used by other node of content type

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

i have a problem regarding fields of type **list**.

The scenario is the following. I have a content type with several fields, among them a field of type **list**. This field have 3 values ("1" to "3"). I want any of those 3 values to belong only in ONE node of this specific content type.

In other words, if a node of that content type has the value "1" in that field, i want that value to be "disabled" when creating new nodes of that content type (so, only available options to be "2" and "3").

Do you have any ideas? Is it possible at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of this usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to build a custom module in which you implement *hook_form_FORM_ID_alter*. since we're dealing with node create/edit forms, try *yourmodule_form_yourcontenttype_node_form_alter()*.

(you could go for *hook_form_alter()*, but that would yield less performance, especially since you have a query to run.)

your implementation should include a query for that specific field, probably the table *field_data_field_yourfield*. narrow it by **bundle** and if it returns any **entity_id**, that's the one you're filtering out of your dropdown.

here's a few links to help you sort things out:

- function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter():
  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x
- function db_select(): https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x
- also look up "D7 Form API reference" (I can't post more than two links atm, sorry)

please write back if it works. good luck!

cheers, 
Luco